# Create multiple class instances under different names

Tags: python, class, instance

I need to create 3 instances of a class from another class that I call, when I loop through the constructor and use the same variable it just initializes the same instance instead of creating a new instance. What is the best way to spin up new instances from within a call?

What I have:

```
def loopInstances(self, x):
    for b in range(3):    
        constructor = self.initialize(**self.kwargs) #each time this is called it does not create a new instance
        constructor.call1(x)
        constructor.call2(x)
```

What I am trying to do:

```
def loopInstances(self, x):        
     constructor1 = self.initialize(**self.kwargs)
     constructor1.call1(x)
     constructor1.call2(x)
     constructor2 = self.initialize(**self.kwargs)
     constructor2.call1(x)
     constructor2.call2(x)
     constructor3 = self.initialize(**self.kwargs)
     constructor3.call1(x)
     constructor3.call2(x)
```

UPDATED (this works):

```
 d = []
 for b in range(len(3)):
    d.append(self.initialize(**self.kwargs))
 for b in range(len(3)):
    const = d[b]
    const.call1(x)
    const.call2(x)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How to create instances should be covered by any basic tutorial, but then it remains unclear what you want to achieve. Are you perhaps asking a so-called "XY question" here?

Comment: when you call the self.initialize it will create a instance, however if you assign it to the variable constructor and then call the same thing again "constructor = self.initialize(**self.kwargs)" it does not create a new instance, my question is what is the best method for looping through and setting it to a different variable each time

Comment: Well, maybe that's an issue with this `initialize` function then? How would you expect anyone here to guess what your code does and what it should do?

Comment: Asked in a different way, how do I change the variable name "constructor" on each loop so that it is "constructor1" then "constructor2" etc.

Comment: Step 1: Run through a Python tutorial. Step 2: Do the same again paying attention to builtin containers (list, set dict).

Comment: From what I can gather, you are trying to create dynamic variables. Don't do that. Use a *list* or any other container. Anyway, if your list version works, then `constructor = self.initialize(**self.kwargs)` *does* create a new object, you just always assign it to the same variable in the loop and each iteration the old one gets garbage collected...

Comment: I am scratching my head, how can `range(len(3))` work, when `int` should not be a valid argument of `len()`